# SQL remove all duplicates from query with inner join (3 tables together)

Tags: duplicates, drop-duplicates

I'm trying to create query with inner join (3 tables altogether) to display only one result per item (in this case it will be MATERIAL_ID).

I have created this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
A.ORDER_ID, A.BATCH_ID, A.MATERIAL_ID, B.MATERIAL_DESC, A.TARGET_QTY, A.DISPENSED_QTY,     A.REMAINING_QTY, A.DISPENSED_UOM, A.DISPENSE_STATUS, B.MATERIAL_TYPE, A.UNIT_PROCEDURE_ID, A.SPLIT_ID, A.BOM_REF_NO, C.CONTAINER_STATUS, C.AREA_ID, C.QTY_STATUS, C.EXPIRE_DATE 
FROM
MM_DISP_MATL_ST A
INNER JOIN 
MM_MATERIAL_SP B
ON A.MATERIAL_ID = B.MATERIAL_ID
INNER JOIN
MM_CONTAINER_ST C
ON B.MATERIAL_ID = C.MATERIAL_ID
AND C.CONTAINER_STATUS = 'Unrestricted' 
AND C.QTY_STATUS IN ('Full','Partial')
WHERE A.ORDER_ID = :pORDER_NUMBER
ORDER BY A.BOM_REF_NO
```

but it gives me all info with duplicates for MATERIAL_ID, AREA_ID AND EXPIRE_DATE.

How can I modify this query to show me only 1 result per MATERIAL_ID or BOM_REF_NO and also to select earliest EXPIRE_DATE?

I tried DISTINCT but gives me duplicates which I don't want. Also adding extra ORDER BY didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You could just say in the where clause that you want the record with the earliest expire date

```
... 
WHERE A.ORDER_ID = :pORDER_NUMBER
  AND  C.EXPIRE_DATE = (SELECT MIN(EXPIRE_DATE) FROM MM_CONTAINER_ST C2
                         WHERE B.MATERIAL_ID = C2.MATERIAL_ID)
ORDER BY A.BOM_REF_NO`
```

Comment: I tried that but now it's not displaying all materials. Also with adding above it still shows duplicates for material_id. Do I need more to be more specific?

Comment: Yes, you will have duplicate material_ids when it is in two containers with the same expire_date .
For a good answer you should show example data for all cases and the expected result